# Gson: Set default value on error

Tags: java, android, json, gson

For example, I have an object

```
class MyObject implements Serializable {
  ...other fields

  public int intValue;

  ...other fields
}
```

And I need to parse json using `TypeToken<MyObject>(){}.getType()`. But sometimes the server can to respond with invalid data:

```
[
  {...intValue:42...}, 
  {...intValue:42...}, 
  {...intValue:"bad server, bad"...}
]
```

How I can set default value on error? i.e. I want to receive an `ArrayList<MyObject>`, where intValue == [0] 42, [1] 42, [2] 100500 (this is my custom default value), without throwing global (for array) exception. Because in case of an Exception (with try/catch) I get absolutely empty list.

Maybe I should to use custom `JsonSerializer<T>` and `JsonDeserializer<T>` for ALL types? Boolean, Integer, MyCustomClass...